# Rust program to print citations in Chicago author-date style

Tags: strings, rust, formatting

I have written a Rust program that lets you input a citation's metadata in a Bibtex-like format and generates a bibliography entry formatted in Markdown that conforms (more or less) to the Chicago Author-Date style described [here](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide/citation-guide-2.html).

Currently, it supports citations for `Book`s, `JournalArticle`s, and `NewspaperArticle`s with any number (>0) of authors. **One of my goals** was to write the code in a way that makes it easy to add a new resource type, say `AcademicThesis`, by creating a `struct AcademicThesis` containing the necessary fields and adding `impl AcademicThesis { citation(&self) -> String { ... }}` that generates the citation.

**A secondary goal** was to make it expandable to other citation styles, but of course this would require first renaming the `citation()` method to something more specific.

**My motivation** for writing this program is that almost all of the coding I do involves numerical schemes like [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/274852/continuous-knapsack-problem-in-rust), and I almost never work with strings at all, but it seems like strings have a lot to teach us about how the Rust language works.

The following are **non-features** that I decided against implementing until I have a firmer grasp of the Rust language:

- Page ranges such as `(455, 468)` are rendered naively as `455–468` instead of `455–68`
- Generates citations only, not a full bibliography (e.g. with line breaks, alphabetization, hanging indents...)

I would appreciate a **general code review.**

Here is the program:

```rust
const MONTHS: [&str; 12] = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

pub struct Date {
    year: u16,
    month: usize,
    day: u16
}

impl Date {
    // Return a string such as "May 23" representing the date
    fn to_month_day(&self) -> String {
        format!(
            "{} {}",
            MONTHS[self.month],
            self.day
        )
    }
}

pub struct Name {
    first: String,
    last: String
}

/// Convert a vector of author names into a string listing them in Chicago style
fn list_authors(authors: &Vec<Name>) -> String {
    match authors.len() {
        0 => panic!("No author given!"),
        1 => format!("{}, {}", authors.first().unwrap().last, authors.first().unwrap().first),
        2 => format!(
            "{}, {} and {} {}",
            authors.first().unwrap().last,
            authors.first().unwrap().first,
            authors.last().unwrap().first,
            authors.last().unwrap().last,
        ),
        _ => {
            let mut s =  format!(
                "{}, {}, ",
                authors.first().unwrap().last,
                authors.first().unwrap().first
            );
            for i in 1..authors.len()-1 {
                s.push_str(&format!(
                    "{} {}, ",
                    authors[i].first,
                    authors[i].last
                ))
            };
            s.push_str(&format!(
                    "and {} {}",
                    authors.last().unwrap().first,
                    authors.last().unwrap().last
            ));
            s
        }
    }
}

/// Convert "str" to "[str](https://str)", which renders as a link in markdown
fn link_to_clickable(url: &String) -> String {
    return format!("[{}](https://{})", url, url);
}

pub struct JournalArticle {
    authors: Vec<Name>,
    year: u16,
    title: String,
    journal: String,
    volume: u16,
    issue: u16,
    pages: (u16, u16),
    url: String
}

impl JournalArticle{
    /// Generate a citation in Chicago style
    fn citation(&self) -> String {
        let author_string = list_authors(&self.authors);

        return format!(
            "{}. {}. &ldquo;{}.&rdquo; *{}* {} ({}): {}&ndash;{}. {}.",
            author_string,
            self.year,
            self.title, 
            self.journal, 
            self.volume,
            self.issue, 
            self.pages.0,
            self.pages.1,
            link_to_clickable(&self.url)
        );
    }
}

pub struct NewspaperArticle {
    authors: Vec<Name>,
    date: Date,
    title: String,
    newspaper: String,
    url: String
}

impl NewspaperArticle {
    /// Generate a citation in Chicago style
    fn citation(&self) -> String {
        let author_string = list_authors(&self.authors);
        let date_string = self.date.to_month_day();

        return format!(
            "{}. {}. &ldquo;{}.&rdquo; *{},* {}. {}.",
            author_string,
            self.date.year,
            self.title, 
            self.newspaper,
            date_string,
            link_to_clickable(&self.url)
        );
    }
}

pub struct Book {
    authors: Vec<Name>,
    year: u16,
    title: String,
    publisher: String,
    location: String
}

impl Book {
    /// Generate a citation in Chicago style
    fn citation(&self) -> String {
        let author_string = list_authors(&self.authors);

        return format!(
            "{}. {}. *{}.* {}: {}.",
            author_string,
            self.year,
            self.title, 
            self.location,
            self.publisher,
        );
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Journal article with one author
    let source = JournalArticle{
        authors: Vec::<Name>::from([Name{
            first: String::from("Aaron"),
            last: String::from("Bodoh&ndash;Creed")
        }]),
        year: 2020,
        title: String::from("Optimizing for Distributional Goals in School Choice Problems"),
        journal: String::from("Management Science"),
        volume: 66,
        issue: 8,
        pages: (3657, 3676),
        url: String::from("doi.org/10.1287/mnsc.2019.3376")
    };

    println!("{}\n", source.citation());

    // Journal article with two authors
    let source = JournalArticle{
        authors: Vec::<Name>::from([Name{
            first: String::from("Paul"),
            last: String::from("Milgrom")
        }, Name{
            first: String::from("John"),
            last: String::from("Roberts")
        }]),
        year: 1990,
        title: String::from("The Economics of Modern Manufacturing: Technology, Strategy, and Organization"),
        journal: String::from("The American Economic Review"),
        volume: 80,
        issue: 3,
        pages: (511, 528),
        url: String::from("jstor.org/stable/2006681")
    };

    println!("{}\n", source.citation());

    // Journal article with three authors
    let source = JournalArticle{
        authors: Vec::<Name>::from([Name{
            first: String::from("Chandra"),
            last: String::from("Chekuri")
        }, Name{
            first: String::from("Jan"),
            last: String::from("Vondrák")
        }, Name{
            first: String::from("Rico"),
            last: String::from("Zenklusen")
        }]),
        year: 2014,
        title: String::from("Submodular Function Maximization via the Multilinear Relaxation and Contention Resolution Schemes"),
        journal: String::from("SIAM Journal on Computing"),
        volume: 43,
        issue: 6,
        pages: (3657, 3676),
        url: String::from("doi.org/10.1137/110839655")
    };

    println!("{}\n", source.citation());

    // Newspaper article
    let source = NewspaperArticle{
        authors: Vec::<Name>::from([Name{
            first: String::from("Kathy Johnson"),  // Middle names can be treated as an extension of first names
            last: String::from("Bowles")
        }]),
        date: Date{day: 24, month: 5, year: 2022},
        title: String::from("Campus Landscapes: So Much More Than Marketing"),
        newspaper: String::from("Inside Higher Ed"),
        url: String::from("insidehighered.com/blogs/just-explain-it-me/campus-landscapes-so-much-more-marketing")
    };

    println!("{}\n", source.citation());

    // Book
    let source = Book{
        authors: Vec::<Name>::from([Name{
            first: String::from("Thomas"),
            last: String::from("Cormen")
        }, Name{
            first: String::from("Charles"),
            last: String::from("Leiserson")
        }, Name{
            first: String::from("Ronald"),
            last: String::from("Rivest")
        }]),
        year: 1996,
        title: String::from("Introduction to Algorithms"),
        publisher: String::from("The MIT Press"),
        location: String::from("Cambridge, Massachusetts")
    };

    println!("{}\n", source.citation());
}
```

It outputs

```markdown
Bodoh&ndash;Creed, Aaron. 2020. &ldquo;Optimizing for Distributional Goals in School Choice Problems.&rdquo; *Management Science* 66 (8): 3657&ndash;3676. [doi.org/10.1287/mnsc.2019.3376](https://doi.org/10.1287/mnsc.2019.3376).

Milgrom, Paul and John Roberts. 1990. &ldquo;The Economics of Modern Manufacturing: Technology, Strategy, and Organization.&rdquo; *The American Economic Review* 80 (3): 511&ndash;528. [jstor.org/stable/2006681](https://jstor.org/stable/2006681).

Chekuri, Chandra, Jan Vondrák, and Rico Zenklusen. 2014. &ldquo;Submodular Function Maximization via the Multilinear Relaxation and Contention Resolution Schemes.&rdquo; *SIAM Journal on Computing* 43 (6): 3657&ndash;3676. [doi.org/10.1137/110839655](https://doi.org/10.1137/110839655).

Bowles, Kathy Johnson. 2022. &ldquo;Campus Landscapes: So Much More Than Marketing.&rdquo; *Inside Higher Ed,* June 24. [insidehighered.com/blogs/just-explain-it-me/campus-landscapes-so-much-more-marketing](https://insidehighered.com/blogs/just-explain-it-me/campus-landscapes-so-much-more-marketing).

Cormen, Thomas, Charles Leiserson, and Ronald Rivest. 1996. *Introduction to Algorithms.* Cambridge, Massachusetts: The MIT Press.
```

Which renders in Markdown as:

> Bodoh–Creed, Aaron. 2020. “Optimizing for Distributional
> Goals in School Choice Problems.” *Management Science* 66 (8):
> 3657–3676.
> [doi.org/10.1287/mnsc.2019.3376](https://doi.org/10.1287/mnsc.2019.3376).
>
> Milgrom, Paul and John Roberts. 1990. “The Economics of Modern
> Manufacturing: Technology, Strategy, and Organization.” *The
> American Economic Review* 80 (3): 511–528.
> [jstor.org/stable/2006681](https://jstor.org/stable/2006681).
>
> Chekuri, Chandra, Jan Vondrák, and Rico Zenklusen. 2014.
> “Submodular Function Maximization via the Multilinear Relaxation
> and Contention Resolution Schemes.” *SIAM Journal on Computing*
> 43 (6): 3657–3676.
> [doi.org/10.1137/110839655](https://doi.org/10.1137/110839655).
>
> Bowles, Kathy Johnson. 2022. “Campus Landscapes: So Much More
> Than Marketing.” *Inside Higher Ed,* June 24.
> [insidehighered.com/blogs/just-explain-it-me/campus-landscapes-so-much-more-marketing](https://insidehighered.com/blogs/just-explain-it-me/campus-landscapes-so-much-more-marketing).
>
> Cormen, Thomas, Charles Leiserson, and Ronald Rivest. 1996.
> *Introduction to Algorithms.* Cambridge, Massachusetts: The MIT Press.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice project! From previous experience writing citation formatting in Rust (just a small side project) I would advise you to not try to follow the standards to the letter, that is just a extreme pile of work that is not worth it. Otherwise really nice work. I attached the code with inline comments below, I prefixed the comments with `Note:` to make it easy to find them back. If you have questions about any of the comments feel free to reach out.

````rust
// Note: I always use clippy to warn me when code can be written in a nicer way.
// See: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy
#![warn(clippy::all, clippy::pedantic, clippy::nursery)] 

const MONTHS: [&str; 12] = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
];

pub struct Date {
    year: u16,
    month: usize,
    day: u16,
}

impl Date {
    /// Return a string such as "May 23" representing the date
    fn to_month_day(&self) -> String {
        format!("{} {}", MONTHS[self.month], self.day)
    }
}

pub struct Name {
    first: String, // Note: some cultures have a slightly different scheme with middle parts, this is commonly added to the last name so it will likely not be a problem, eg Dutch/Flemish: Erik van Huffelen (mind the casing!).
    last: String,
}

impl Name {
    // Note: I personally really like this pattern where you have a function/constructor that
    // takes a `impl into<String>` and calls `.into()`. In this way I very rarely have to think
    // about the exact string type any more as it will automatically do all the stuff. And
    // because it is Rust this will be just as fast as doing it 'by hand' (I assume, I have no
    // reason to believe otherwise).
    // This can of course be done just as easily for the Citation types. And `Into` is a very
    // prevalent trait that can be used in very many places.
    pub fn new(first: impl Into<String>, last: impl Into<String>) -> Self {
        Self {
            first: first.into(),
            last: last.into(),
        }
    }
}

/// Convert a vector of author names into a string listing them in Chicago style
fn list_authors(authors: &[Name]) -> String {
    // Note: I followed clippy here and replaced `&Vec<Name>` with `&[Name]` same explanation as `link_to_clickable` (line 80).
    match authors.len() {
        0 => panic!("No author given!"),
        1 => format!("{}, {}", authors[0].last, authors[0].first), // Note; I used direct indexing here into the array as the index is known and it takes less space visually, it is definitely not wrong to use `first` or `last`. I just want to show you some other ways ;-).
        2 => format!(
            "{}, {} and {} {}",
            authors[0].last, authors[0].first, authors[1].first, authors[1].last,
        ),
        _ => {
            let mut output = format!("{}, {}, ", authors[0].last, authors[0].first);
            for author in authors.iter().take(authors.len() - 1).skip(1) {
                // Note: clippy advised this, but I am not sure if I agree, make your own choice here.
                output.push_str(&format!("{} {}, ", author.first, author.last));
            }
            output.push_str(&format!(
                "and {} {}",
                authors.last().unwrap().first,
                authors.last().unwrap().last
            ));
            output
        }
    }
}

/// Convert "str" to "[str](https://str)", which renders as a link in markdown
fn link_to_clickable(url: &str) -> String {
    // Note: this way it is more general, any `&String` can automatically be dereferenced into `&str`.
    // Using `&String` is essentially the same from the borrow standpoint, it gives you read access to
    // a piece of text. Specifying `&String` makes it so that you cannot use this functions with a
    // `&'static str` or a slice/simple operation of a string, eg [`String::trim`] returns a `&str`.
    return format!("[{url}](https://{url})"); // Note: You can directly include variables in format strings.
}

// Note: As you a creating a shared behaviour for a couple of structs introducing a `trait` seems to me
// like a logical choice. You could also create a single `enum` with all options, but that gives a slightly
// different code architecture you might not like in certain cases. (Like not having the option for downstream
// users to implement the trait on their own structs.)
pub trait Citation {
    /// Generate a citation in Chicago style
    fn citation(&self) -> String;

    // Note: You could write an extra method which prepares the citation output for markdown.
    fn md_citation(&self) -> String {
        // Note: this is an example of course you would add more cases for the other special chars. Each
        // call to `replace` copies the whole string, if this is a problem you could look into a loop over
        // all chars concatenating everything with the special encoding in one round.
        self.citation().replace('-', "&ndash");

        // Note: here is an example of the single copy replacement.
        let citation = self.citation();
        let mut output = String::with_capacity(citation.len());
        for c in citation.chars() {
            match c {
                '-' => output += "&ndash;",
                n => output.push(n),
            }
        }
        output
    }
}

pub struct JournalArticle {
    authors: Vec<Name>,
    year: u16,
    title: String,
    journal: String,
    volume: u16,
    issue: u16,
    pages: (u16, u16),
    url: String,
}

impl Citation for JournalArticle {
    fn citation(&self) -> String {
        // Note: I tend to like 'one-liners' above introduced variables that are used only once. If needed the name of the variable being used as documentation can be replaced by a real comment ;-).
        format!(
            "{}. {}. &ldquo;{}.&rdquo; *{}* {} ({}): {}&ndash;{}. {}.",
            list_authors(&self.authors),
            self.year,
            self.title,
            self.journal,
            self.volume,
            self.issue,
            self.pages.0,
            self.pages.1,
            link_to_clickable(&self.url)
        ) // Note: here the return is not necessary
    }
}

pub struct NewspaperArticle {
    authors: Vec<Name>,
    date: Date,
    title: String,
    newspaper: String,
    url: String,
}

impl Citation for NewspaperArticle {
    fn citation(&self) -> String {
        format!(
            "{}. {}. &ldquo;{}.&rdquo; *{},* {}. {}.",
            list_authors(&self.authors),
            self.date.year,
            self.title,
            self.newspaper,
            self.date.to_month_day(),
            link_to_clickable(&self.url)
        )
    }
}

pub struct Book {
    authors: Vec<Name>,
    year: u16,
    title: String,
    publisher: String,
    location: String,
}

impl Book {
    pub fn new(
        authors: impl Into<Vec<Name>>,
        year: u16,
        title: impl Into<String>,
        publisher: impl Into<String>,
        location: impl Into<String>,
    ) -> Self {
        Self {
            authors: authors.into(),
            year,
            title: title.into(),
            publisher: publisher.into(),
            location: location.into(),
        }
    }
}

impl Citation for Book {
    fn citation(&self) -> String {
        format!(
            "{}. {}. *{}.* {}: {}.",
            list_authors(&self.authors),
            self.year,
            self.title,
            self.location,
            self.publisher,
        )
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Note: it is best to write these tests as unit tests so that reviewers (and you!) can be certain about
    // their refactorings. See below for how this is done with the book example.

    // Journal article with one author
    let source = JournalArticle {
        // Note: here you can see the impact of the `new` function with `impl Into<String>`. Additionally I
        // have an IDE which shows the names of parameters in-line once the definition becomes large, this
        // makes it so that the explicit names of the fields are not really necessary any more.
        authors: vec![Name::new("Aaron", "Bodoh&ndash;Creed")],
        year: 2020,
        title: String::from("Optimizing for Distributional Goals in School Choice Problems"),
        journal: String::from("Management Science"),
        volume: 66,
        issue: 8,
        pages: (3657, 3676),
        url: String::from("doi.org/10.1287/mnsc.2019.3376"),
    };

    println!("{}\n", source.citation());

    // Journal article with two authors
    let source = JournalArticle {
        authors: vec![
            Name {
                first: String::from("Paul"),
                last: String::from("Milgrom"),
            },
            Name {
                first: String::from("John"),
                last: String::from("Roberts"),
            },
        ],
        year: 1990,
        title: String::from(
            "The Economics of Modern Manufacturing: Technology, Strategy, and Organization",
        ),
        journal: String::from("The American Economic Review"),
        volume: 80,
        issue: 3,
        pages: (511, 528),
        url: String::from("jstor.org/stable/2006681"),
    };

    println!("{}\n", source.citation());

    // Journal article with three authors
    let source = JournalArticle{
        authors: vec![Name{
            first: String::from("Chandra"),
            last: String::from("Chekuri")
        }, Name{
            first: String::from("Jan"),
            last: String::from("Vondrák")
        }, Name{
            first: String::from("Rico"),
            last: String::from("Zenklusen")
        }],
        year: 2014,
        title: String::from("Submodular Function Maximization via the Multilinear Relaxation and Contention Resolution Schemes"),
        journal: String::from("SIAM Journal on Computing"),
        volume: 43,
        issue: 6,
        pages: (3657, 3676),
        url: String::from("doi.org/10.1137/110839655")
    };

    println!("{}\n", source.citation());

    // Newspaper article
    let source = NewspaperArticle {
        authors: vec![Name {
            first: String::from("Kathy Johnson"), // Middle names can be treated as an extension of first names
            last: String::from("Bowles"),
        }],
        date: Date {
            day: 24,
            month: 5,
            year: 2022,
        },
        title: String::from("Campus Landscapes: So Much More Than Marketing"),
        newspaper: String::from("Inside Higher Ed"),
        url: String::from(
            "insidehighered.com/blogs/just-explain-it-me/campus-landscapes-so-much-more-marketing",
        ),
    };

    println!("{}\n", source.citation());
}

#[cfg(test)] // Note: cfg is conditional compilation, so the compiler will not even look at the code in
             // this module when compiling in a normal mode, this improves the compiling performance somewhat.
mod tests {
    use super::*; // Note: this imports everything of the outer module (the one you are testing).

    #[test]
    fn book() {
        // Book
        // Note: arrays can be cast `Into` vecs!
        let source = Book::new(
            [
                Name::new("Thomas", "Cormen"),
                Name::new("Charles", "Leiserson"),
                Name::new("Ronald", "Rivest"),
            ],
            1996,
            "Introduction to Algorithms",
            "The MIT Press",
            "Cambridge, Massachusetts",
        );

        assert_eq!(
            source.citation(), 
            "Cormen, Thomas, Charles Leiserson, and Ronald Rivest. 1996. *Introduction to Algorithms.* Cambridge, Massachusetts: The MIT Press."
        );
    }
}
```
````

Comment: (Viewer discretion advised: assembly) I have tried the generated assembly for the `impl Into<String>` and `String` parameters and from what I can see (not very accustomed to reading/working with assembly) the generated code is exactly equal:  https://rust.godbolt.org/z/eP7KEf8G9. So there should not be any performance reason to not go with this 'style'.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was a really, really helpful review. I like replacing the vector of `Name`s with a slices: it makes the input much more readable.

Comment: `s.push_str(&format!(/* ... */))` causes an additional allocation in `format!`.  `write!(&mut s, /* ... */)` is more efficient (in theory).